# Laravel pivot table is adding `GroupMembers`.`GroupId` is null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am bulding an application with members and groups and a member can be in a group.

Using the laravel framework

I have the following Models:

```
class Group extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Groups';
    public function GroupMembers()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Member', 'GroupMembers', 'GroupId', 'MemberId');
    }

}

class Member extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'members';
    protected static $rules = [
        'Name' => 'unique:members'
    ];

    public function Groups()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Group', 'GroupMembers', 'MemberId', 'GroupId');
    }


}
```

When i try to get all the groupmembers of a group with:

```
public function getIndex()
{

    $member = Group::findOrFail(3);
    //$member = Member::findOrFail(1);
    //$results = $member;

    $results = $member->GroupMembers;
    dd(DB::getQueryLog());
    dd($results);
    //$results =GroupMember::getGroupMembers(1);


    return View::make('hello')->with('results', $results);
}
```

I get 0 results because it is adding is null to the query :

```
select  `members`.*
,       `GroupMembers`.`GroupId` as `pivot_GroupId`
,       `GroupMembers`.`MemberId` as `pivot_MemberId`
,       `GroupMembers`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`
,       `GroupMembers`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` 
from    
        `members` 
inner join 
        `GroupMembers` on `members`.`id` = `GroupMembers`.`MemberId` 
where 
    `GroupMembers`.`GroupId` is null
```

Where is that comming from and how do i delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming `GroupId` and `MembersId` are the primary keys of the respective table?
You need to define any primary key column name that differs from the default (`id`)

Add this to your models

```
protected $primaryKey = 'GroupId';
```